# Behavior of Initialization Blocks

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

I have code which I am unable to understand, how it produces that output. Here is the code below-

#### Code:

```
class Bird {
  { System.out.print("b1 "); }
  public Bird() { System.out.print("b2 "); }
}
class Raptor extends Bird {
  static { System.out.print("r1 "); }
  public Raptor() { System.out.print("r2 "); }
  { System.out.print("r3 "); }
  static { System.out.print("r4 "); }
}
class Hawk extends Raptor {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("pre ");
    new Hawk();
    System.out.println("hawk ");
  }
}
```

#### Output:

`r1 r4 pre b1 b2 r3 r2 hawk`

### Questions:

My specific questions regarding this code are-

1. When `Hawk` class  is instationed, it cause `Raptor` class to be instationed, and hence the static code block runs first. But then, static code should be followed by non-static ones, before printing `pre`. Isn't it?
2. Those non-static initialization blocks seem to be actually acting like constructors. So, can these be used as constructors in regular programming?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> static code should be followed by non-static ones, before printing pre. Isn't it?

1. Running `Hawk.main` triggers the initialization of all three classes. This is when the static intitializers run;
2. `pre` is printed;
3. `new Hawk()` triggers the execution of instance initializers for all three classes.

> can these be used as constructors in regular programming?

They end up compiled together with code from constructors into `<init>` methods. So yes, they are similar to constructor code. The key difference is that they run regardless of which constructor runs, and run before the constructor body.

Comment: So, they run every time a new instance is created?

Comment: @PrateekSingla yes initializers are run every time an object is created.

Comment: *instance initializers* initialize each instance. *class (static) initializers* initialize the class.

Answer (score 3):

The `static` blocks are run when the class is loaded therefore they run even before your method `main()` runs.

The initializer blocks are run before the constructors. The difference between a constructor and a initializer block is that a constractor can have parameters.

Also be aware that the initializer blocks and constructors run first in the base class and afterwards in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

1 - The pre is printed first, because you are actually creating Hawk only when running new Hawk(), until that moment, only static initializers are going to be executed.

2 - Non-static initialization are usually applied to initiliaze values from variables, but since you can't pass parameters to them, you are unlikely going to achieve the same compared to constructors. In these blocks, you may initialize your attributes to constant values or empty values.

Comment: A hawk should be the preferred authority on hawks.

Answer (score 0):

1. The static initializers are run first (actually in the order of definition)
2. You may use initializer blocks, but it is a common idiom to initialize fields at the declaration or in the constructor.

The [Java tutorials document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) this in detail.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to run some initialization in initializer block because there you can access files (e.g. load RSA keys).

Comment: It may be easier to write, but is it easier to test :-)?